# Complete the sequence (easy)

Tags: number-sequence

What three-digit numbers best complete the following sequence:

> 33, 45, 54, 32, 11, 23, ___?

There are two possible answers. One is composite and one is prime. Find both.

Comment: *Three*-digit?...

Comment: @nicael Yes, three-digit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answers are

> $322$ (composite) and $211$ (prime)

Reasoning

> If you convert the numbers into musical notes so that $1, 2, 3$ are the   'do', 're', 'mi' of the musical scale, then the sequence with the composite number ending corresponds to the first line of "Ode to Joy" (from Beethoven's $9$th symphony) and the sequence with the prime number ending corresponds to the second line.

Comment: Nice try. However if you don't get both answers at the same time, that means your answer is probably incorrect. (I should've put it this way :) )

Comment: Okay, I've had a better idea.

Comment: I've edited my answer to something different.

Comment: Lol, how was it supposed to be *easy*? Not really obvious.

Comment: lol maybe a riddle always seems easy to its author. :P

Comment: Would be interesting to see in the answer how this occurred to you

Comment: I don't really understand why these were grouped in pairs. The notes are crotchets, four to a bar.